# Add job inside another job for APSchedule

Tags: fastapi, apscheduler

I am using APScheduler in a FastAPI application. I have a table, where I stored my async tasks. Then, using APScheduler, I would like to read this table every hour and add new jobs (one per row of the table) to the queue. These jobs are light, so using celery is overkilling I feel. However, I have difficulty in starting a job inside another job for APScheduler.
So, the question is how a job can be added inside another job? Any ideas or help are appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had a problem with this and a simple solution is to have the scheduler as a global variable available in the job's module. You might also have to use the memory store, as it allows for passing unserializable objects.

You can also pass the scheduler to the job, as long as the job is being run on an executor that doesn't require the arguments to be serialized.

For example, you can have a periodic job running on the asyncio executor that gets the scheduler as an argument, and adds further jobs to it, that are to be run with the ProcessPool executor.

For more info, refer to this [discussion in the Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/apscheduler/Lobby?at=6286711eef00bd1dc6ebef56)